# between here (node:4216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: node.js, discord.js, helper

```
bot.on("message", message => {
  const idbotcreate = "59507x88558x951x16";
  if (message.author.id !== idbotcreate) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith("help")) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send(token);
```

if(!message.author === userID)

I made this code, but it doesn't work

I would like when I start my bot, it would send me what I want

my idm is not blocked, when I type help this error my idm is not blocked, when I type help this error

(node:4216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

and I didn't want to have to type help for him to send me the token, someone help me?

or it would be better if the bot sent it to me in email

Answer (score 1):

`idbotcreate` must be a valid user ID. Additionally, bots cannot send messages to each other.

To get the ID of your bot, just do `bot.user.id`

```js
bot.on("message", message => {
  const idbotcreate = bot.user.id;
  if (message.author.id !== idbotcreate) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith("help")) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send(token);
```

Comment: I wanted the token to be sent to me in some way, it wouldn't have to be through discord, by email, it could be good

Comment: Then you should look into [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) However, my answer has answered the problem you were facing.